# The Visual Studio Code debugger does not show source-compiled Pyscf code, but can execute the library functions line by line

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, configuration, compilation, vscode-debugger

I am having trouble using the Visual Code debugger with a [source-compiled version of the Pyscf library](https://pyscf.org/install.html#compiling-from-source-code). Specifically, the debugger does not show the code while executing, but I can still control it line by line.

While it says "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found", I can still execute the file line by line, not being able to see the code though. [image: Screenshot of the debugger executing a mf.get_init() function from pyscf.]

The configuration I implemented was to add the pyscf path to the option Extra Paths in the configuration of Visual Studio. This allows me to freely open and see the library files, which are located on my Developer folder in my Mac, as long as I am not in debugger mode.

Comment: By the way, perhaps I should have indicated it, but it is not a `justMyCode=false` issue. It indicates the line being executed and the variable values (see left column in the image). Furthermore, outside the environment, I can navigate through the pyscf python code.